# What are the benefits of such flexible "self-identifiers" in F#?

Tags: f#, language-features

While I understand [self-identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx#Y1944) in F#, I am puzzled as to the benefits of such flexibility.  Why does F# not just support `this.Blah` as C# does and be done with it?  I'm guessing some people use it to improve readability, but even that seems a stretch.  So, what are the uses/benefits of this language feature?

*For the un-initiated, below is an example that defines a type-wide self identifier "self" and a method scoped identifier "this".  The example is taken from the MSDN article linked above.*

```
type MyClass2(dataIn) as self =
   let data = dataIn
   do
       self.PrintMessage()
   member this.PrintMessage() =
       printf "Creating MyClass2 with Data %d" data
```

Comment: So you can do: `member this.this = this` of course!

Comment: @gradbot - What about `Me`? We don't want the large demographic of programmers coming from VB to feel left out.

Comment: I can't think of any compelling benefit.

Comment: I wish I could write `member _.PrintMessage() =`, to indicate that I'm not using `this`

Comment: @Tim Robinson: its not quite the same, but I usually use __ (i.e. double underscore) to indicate that I'm not using the self-reference

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One small advantage is that you can use them to differentiate an object expression's `this` from that of the type which has created it:

```
type IExample = abstract GetAnObject : unit -> obj

type MyClass() = 
  member outer.Example1 = { new IExample with member inner.GetAnObject() = upcast inner }
  member outer.Example2 = { new IExample with member inner.GetAnObject() = upcast outer }
```

A potential philosophical reason is that it makes it seem like the `this` reference is not too different from any other argument.  If you should be able to name the other arguments (instead of being forced to use `arg1`, `arg2`, etc.), then why shouldn't you be able to name the first argument as you please, too?

Comment: Think about the bizarre context-sensitive behavior of `this` in JavaScript and the simplicity of this (no pun intended) seems brilliant.

Comment: That's a pretty good advantage. Just thought I'd mention that in Java, you would access the outer instance using `MyClass.this`, and in Javascript you do a lot of `var that = this;`. I think I prefer Java's approach, again for consistency.

Comment: Oh, and interesting philosophical argument, however, I'd argue that if every function had exactly one argument, I'd be content with being forced to use `arg`. :)

Comment: Nice answer, thanks.  _As an F# newbie I had to go and learn about object expressions before I could understand why it was a good answer :)_

Comment: @Stephen - I can see your code now: `let x arg = let y arg = let z arg = arg + arg; z arg; y arg` :)

Comment: @Daniel - I prefer `let x = (fun arg -> (let y = (fun arg -> (let z = (fun (arg:int) -> arg + arg; arg; 1) in z)) in y))` ;)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can come up with (and it's not big) is that since the self-identifier must explicitly be referred to when calling an instance method, being able to name it lets you use something shorter than the word `this`. There is a lot of (valid or not) desire in languages on FP languages on which F# is based for conciseness (sometimes to the point of overdoing it) that may have prompted this. After all, you'll note this desire showing through in other places in F# where it wouldn't in e.g. C#--note function names like `iteri` that would probably be called `IterateWithIndex` in C#.