# F# How to use an interface in a separate module

Tags: f#

So I have been doing research on interfaces on F#. I have found these 2 articles on it. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233207.aspx)  and [F# for fun and profit](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/interfaces/) But unfortunately they are only skin deep.

**UPDATED**

here is my module with my interfaces

```
//open statements omitted for brevity

 module DrawingInterfaces =

    ///gets a string representation of the SVG code representation of the object
   type IRepresentable_SVG =
      abstract member getSVGRepresenation : unit -> string

//other interfaces omitted for brevity
```

Now within the same namespace and physical folder also I have this:

```
 type lineSet (x1off,x2off,y1off,y2off,x1,x2,y1,y2,rot,rotOff,count) =

    //tons of member vals omitted for brevity

  member val x1Start = x1 with get, set

  interface  DrawingInterfaces.IRepresentable_SVG with 
            member __.getSVGRepresenation() = 

                let mutable svg = ""
                let mutable currentx1 = x1Start
                svg
```

This used to  give me 2 errors, before I was using the __. notation for the member.  The first error was on  the interface line. And a second on the member line.
The errors were respectively:

```
The type 'IRepresentable_SVG' is not defined


This instance member needs a parameter to represent the object being invoked.
```

I was able to fix the first one by changing the file order. Thanks to John Palmer.
The second one is nearly fixed./

After using the __ . notation I was able to get rid of the second error. However, now a new error pops up when I try to use type members in my interface implementation.

```
      let mutable currentx1 = x1Start
```

x1Start shows as not being defined. I need to be able to use values stored in my other members within my implementation.

Comment: F# is sensitive to file compilation order.  Is the definition file above the usage file in Visual Studio?

Comment: Changing the compile order fixed the first problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first make it work and then point to your problems. I define below 2 separate modules in 2 separate `.fs` files within the same namespace `Example` for interface **definition** in module `Example.DrawingInterfaces`and interface **implementation** in module `Example.UseInterface` and also a console app that will **use** the interface from third ([implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233221.aspx)) module `Program`. In my project correspondent code files are in the following order: `DefInterface.fs`, `UseInterface,fs`, `Program.fs` (I also made few idiomatic styling changes and more brevity omissions)

**File: DefInterface.fs**

```
namespace Example
module DrawingInterfaces =
   type IRepresentable_SVG =
      abstract member GetSVGRepresenation : unit -> string
```

**File: UseInterface.fs**

```
namespace Example
module UseInterface =
    type LineSet (x1) =
        member val X1Start = x1 with get, set
        interface DrawingInterfaces.IRepresentable_SVG with 
            member __.GetSVGRepresenation() = "test" + " " + __.X1Start.ToString()
```

**File: Program.fs**

```
open Example
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let lineSet = UseInterface.LineSet(5)
    let example : DrawingInterfaces.IRepresentable_SVG = lineSet :> _
    example.GetSVGRepresenation() |> printfn "%A"
    lineSet.X1Start <- 10
    example.GetSVGRepresenation() |> printfn "%A"
    0
```

Compile, run and make sure it works.

Now to problems in your code:

- first error message stems from the need to refer to the full implemented interface name in `UseInterface.fs`, which is **`Example.DrawingInterfaces.IRepresentable_SVG`** although as both modules belong to the same namespace the `Example` prefix may be omitted
- second error message points to the need of using **instance** method in implementation class `UseInterface.LineSet`, which is achieved by prepending [self-identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd483468.aspx) `__.` to the method signature

Finally, notice the usage of your interface in `Program.fs` that imports namespace, provides module names for definition and implementation respectively, and also explicitly casts implementation `LineSet` to `IRepresentable_SVG`.

**EDIT:** I've added `X1Start` property to the original `LineSet` to show how it can be used from interface implementation per question author's request. Now self-id `__.` is more involved and probably using `self.` or even `this.` instead would make more sense.

Comment: Interesting choice for a self-identifier :)

Comment: I come from a Java and recently C# background. I am finding it hard to relate or understand this self identifier concept. Can you explain it a bit or point me to an article that does. From my background, a method name was just a method name. In C# or Java implementing interfaces methods was very simple. I am assuming, some degree of flexibility was gained for the increased learning curve for F# interfaces and self identifiers.

Comment: There is very nice [Q&A upon self identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355334/what-are-the-benefits-of-such-flexible-self-identifiers-in-f) here on SO along with very thoughtful comments. Besides, it points out when using self-id `__.` makes sense.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. But why is it necessary/required to use a self identifier for the interface in my case. The examples that I saw did not use them.  Also, how can I access other member variables within my implementation of the interface, as per the last 3 lines of my updated question?

Comment: I've edited my snippets per your request. There is nothing special about `__.` id, just a reflection of intent that I originally did not use it anyhow. Now using something like `self.` or even `this.` if the latter helps understanding, is more appropriate.

Comment: That is so weird that I have to use __. to refer to the member within the class when I want to use them, but not for let bindings. Well, I do appreciate the help very much.